# How to add "colSpan" attribute in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm getting the error "**Type string is not assignable to type number**" when I try to add a **colSpan="2"** attribute to the below ReactJS TypeScript code.  How can I fix this?

```
class ProductCategoryRow extends React.Component<MyProps, MyState> {
   constructor(props: MyProps) {
      super(props);
   }
   render() {
      return (<div>
         <tr><th colSpan="2">{ this.props.category }</th></tr>
      </div>);
   } //end render.
} //end class.
```

Comment: Try `colSpan={2}` - you are currently assigning a string value, to assign other types use `{` and return the value.  Can be a function call or literal or whatever.  e.g. `colSpan={getColSpanSize()}`

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

Comment: @ctrlplusb - Thanks, I believe that worked.

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/q/38302507/104380

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Have you tried `<th colSpan={2}>{ this.props.category}</th>`?

Comment: yes in HTML colspan="2" here it will be like string and colspan is expected like an attribute. so in React colspan is colSpan and for "2" we are getting {2} which am not even sure about