# React colspan not working

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dom, reactjs

Why colspan attribute doesn't have effect in React? I created simple component which renders the following:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">people are...</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>monkeys</td>
    <td>donkeys</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and what I get is:

[image]

Am I missing something?

**Edit: SOLVED**

Here is the solution. React expects the attribute name as *colSpan*, not colspan. Figured this out after wasting ridiculous amount of time to discover this little evil fact.

Comment: There was nothing problem in your code I see. Can you tell more details? Here is the fiddle. You can see that colspan is working well. https://jsfiddle.net/m2jknr70/

Comment: Read the edited post. React doesn't like old school html syntax

Comment: Please create answer instead of adding it into the question text. It is perfectly legal on SO to answer your own questions.

Comment: Future visitors: Also make sure you've not added a table-irrelevant tag such as `<div></div>` inside the table structure somewhere. If that's the case and you need it, replace it with a `<></>` pair.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From React's [DOM Differences](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-differences.html) documentation:

> All DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers) should be camelCased to be consistent with standard JavaScript style.

If you check your browser's console, you'll see that React warns you about this:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.2.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.2.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <table border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="2">people are...</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>monkeys</td>
          <td>donkeys</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<App who="World"/>, document.querySelector('#app'))

</script>
```

```
Warning: Unknown DOM property colspan. Did you mean colSpan?
    in th (created by App)
    in tr (created by App)
    in tbody (created by App)
    in table (created by App)
    in App
```

Answer (score 57):

In addition to changing the case, I also had to change the value from a string to a number.

Instead of this:

```
<td colspan='6' />
```

I had to do this:

```
<td colSpan={6} />
```

Answer (score 9):

I had a bit of a different case,  but the final solution for me was to actually giving the th/td a `display: table-cell;` property.

Comment: thanks, this was my problem as well

Answer (score 5):

`colspan` property is in camelCase like `colSpan`. So instead of `colspan` we need to use `colSpan`.

In React v16.12 you can still supply the value as either `int`, like so `colSpan={4}` or `string`, like so: `colSpan="4"`.

Comment: It doesn'n really matter - HTML tag names and attribute names are case-insensitive

Comment: @fen1x React is a lot stricter than vanilla HTML is.

Comment: @fen1x It does matter in react, I have experienced same in my current project.

Comment: @fen1x It is not HTML actually, it is called JSX which is very similar to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put colSpan at the end before closing the opening tag for some reason it wasn't working in the beginning as the first prop.

Answer (score 0):

I tried colSpan with only one td in tr but for me, it didn't work out and if I put another empty td in the same tr it worked.
So the code looked like this

```
<table>

<tr>
<th>First</th>
<th>Second</th>
<th>Third</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colSpan={3}>lorem ipsum</td>
<td></td> <-- Using this empty <td> worked
</tr>

</table>
```

by using that last empty td it worked for me